# Cropping overlapping timespans by priority in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, timespan, gaps-and-islands

I have a large database table with timespans described by `start` and `stop` time. Easy timespan has a priority and the timespans might overlap each other.

I need to process it so that overlaps will be removed.
In case of an overlap, the span with a higher priority will take precedence and the timespan with lower priority will be cropped so that the two doesn't overlap.
If a time span is completely overlapped by one or more timespans with higher priority, it should be removed.

A simple example table:

```
SELECT
    1 AS id,
    {ts '2012-09-24 10:00:00'} AS start,
    {ts '2012-09-24 11:00:00'} AS stop,
    10 AS priority
INTO #TABLE
UNION ALL SELECT 2, {ts '2012-09-24 10:15:00'}, {ts '2012-09-24 12:00:00'}, 5
UNION ALL SELECT 3, {ts '2012-09-24 10:30:00'}, {ts '2012-09-24 12:30:00'}, 1
UNION ALL SELECT 4, {ts '2012-09-24 11:30:00'}, {ts '2012-09-24 13:00:00'}, 15

SELECT * FROM #TABLE;
DROP TABLE #TABLE;
```

Should result in:

```
Start              Stop               Priority
2012-09-24 10:00   2012-09-24 11:00   10
2012-09-24 11:00   2012-09-24 11:30   5
2012-09-24 11:30   2012-09-24 13:00   15
```

It is possible, but I can't find any simple solution to it. Preferably I would like to avoid using cursors. But if there is no other way, well, cursors it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
;with cte as 
(select start as timepoint from @table union select stop from @table)
,cte2 as (select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by timepoint) rn from cte) 

    select id, MIN(ts) as starttime, max(te) as stoptime, maxpri
    from @table t2
        inner join
        (               
        select ts, te, MAX(priority) as maxpri 
        from @table t1
            inner join
            (       
            select c1.rn, c1.timepoint as ts, c2.timepoint as te 
            from cte2 c1
            inner join cte2 c2 on c1.rn+1 = c2.rn
            ) v
            on t1.start<v.te and t1.stop>v.ts
        group by ts, te
        ) v
            on t2.priority = v.maxpri
            and ts>=start and te<=stop
        group by id, maxpri
        order by starttime
```

Comment: I think you are on to something. However, currently the code does not return the expected result. Row id = 2 will is removed instead of cropped to the timestamp 11:00 - 11:30 where none of the other higher priority timespans overlap. I will analyze your code to see if it is correctable.

Comment: @ANisus Are you sure? I get 10:00-11:00 10, 11:00-11:30 5, 11:30-13:00 15 as expected?

Comment: You do? Okay, I will try again. Yikes! Okay.. my mistake. I had error in my in data. Great! Thanks for a nice working solution!